Why an inurl: url is has the largest number of Google Search impressions in my website?
Taking a look to the Google Search Console in my website, it seems that inurl:mystery is producing the largest number of impressions:

Is this a query people actually use or there is another reason behind it?

Unless one of those people happens to browse this website, the rest of us would just be guessing as to their motivations.
